# jQuery returned through AJAX not showing any effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two webpages. Page 1 is a form on whose submit, page 2 is loaded through jQuery (calls a php page and returns the output on the same page1 without load). I have session variables maintained to ensure no breaching is done. However, in a particular scenario, I want page 1 window to close and hence I pass the following code as o/p from page 2.

```
echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:5px"><font color=red>Multiple sessions of the same page are open. Please <a href="" onclick="window.close();">close</a> use the latest window for submission</font></div>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function parent_close(){
    parent.window.close();  
}
setTimeout(parent_close,5000);  
</script>';
```

however, it seems neither clicking the 'close' link closes the main window nor does the window automatically close in 5secs (which is what i actually desire)

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: BTW, the `<font>` tag was deprecated about 50 years ago.

Comment: @j08691 lol, Not true.. The `<font>` tags are deprecated in HTML 4.01 which was published in 1999. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link should have a value in its href, not just an empty value, e.g:

```
href="#"
```

and not:

```
href=""
```

Also, the first argument to `setTimeout` should be enclosed in quotes, and you probably want the function to be invoked, not returned e.g:

```
setTimeout("parent_close()",5000);
```

Comment: tried..but yet doesnt work. Actually the point to note is that the above script is the result of jquery.post invoked from a button clicked on page1. inshort this code is dynamically added to the parent page. Not sure it is binded properly or what

Comment: that's not true, @danwellman, setTimeout receives a function as first argument, it can either receive a string for eval, but the code Sunny's using works perfectly

Comment: The first parameter of setTimeout should always be a function reference and no string

Answer (score 0):

You cannot close a top window through javascript, unless you have opened it with javascript also. Sorry, it cannot be done.

Try copying just the line

```
top.window.close();
```

to the console. run it and see what happens: nothing.

If you put a

```
console.log('here')
```

inside your parent_close function, you will see that the statement is executed...

Comment: what if i write the parent close function in page1 but call it as part of page2 output. WOuld it work then?

Comment: I really think you can only call window.close() to windows that have been opened with window.open() but i might be wrong...